# Print out all elements of a stack/queue

Tags: java, printing, stack, queue, tostring

I am trying to go through a stack and a queue and print out the Object's values. In my Object's class I have implemented a toString. My stack and queue classes use a linked list. I tried going through it with a for loop like an array first, obviously doesn't work. I know how to get the top but not all of them.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
System.out.println(storageA[i].toString());
}
```

storageA is my stack with fixed size of 10.

Comment: You have a bug on line 31.

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Add some code please, that will help everyone to understand and resolve your issue.

Comment: Hey @user2963286 if you were given the above ` for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
System.out.println(storageA[i].toString());
}` would you have any clew?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to iterate over the complete list holding Objects of type E:

```
for (E element : storageA) {
  System.out.println(element.toString());
}
```

If you really only want elements 0-9 (better validate storageA.size > 9, else you get an IndexOutOfBoundsException):

```
for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
   System.out.println(storageA.get(i).toString());
}
```

Comment: I've never seen a for loop like that before. Does it work the same in that if there is are blank element it will print null or a blank line?

Comment: what do you mean by "blank element"? If the element is a null reference, you would of course get a null pointer exception in the toString() call, otherwise you get the return value of your overridden toString() method.

Comment: It's a concept found in many languages: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach)