# Values in priority queue are deleted as soon as I am outside the function, why?

Tags: java

I am calling a function to create priority queue from another function.

```
void readparameters() throws NumberFormatException, IOException
{

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FB2010-1Hr-150-0.txt"))) {
            while (br.ready()) {
                Coflow_All.add(br.readLine());
            }
        }
        Framework.size = Coflow_All.size();
        System.out.println("\nThere are "+Framework.size+" coflows entries\n");


        for(queue_entry=1;queue_entry<=15;queue_entry++)
        {
            //Extract a Coflow and satisfy conditions

            ArrayList<Integer> Coflow_each = new ArrayList<Integer>();


            String input = Coflow_All.get(coflow_pick);
            int find=input.indexOf(":");
            if (find != -1) 
            {   
                //this will give substring
                input= input.substring(0 , find); 
            }

            String[] numbers = input.split(" "); 
            for (String s : numbers) 
            {
               Coflow_each.add(Integer.parseInt(s));           
            }   
            //System.out.println(Coflow_each);

            createqueue(Coflow_each.get(0),Coflow_each.get(1),Coflow_each.get(2),Coflow_each.get(4));
            coflow_pick++;

        }

 void createqueue(int id,int Arrivaltime,int mappers_req,int reducers_req) throws NumberFormatException
    {
         Framework.list.clear();


        Collections.addAll(Framework.list, Arrivaltime,mappers_req,reducers_req);
        //System.out.println("The list is "+Framework.list);

        //Analyze the parameters in Framework.list and then do the entry in queue   

        for(int i=1;i<=mappers_req;i++)
        {
        Queue1.add(new Create_queue(id,Framework.list));
        System.out.println(Queue1.size());
        queue_entry++;

        }       
        java.util.Iterator<Create_queue> it = Queue1.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(Queue1.poll().toString());
        }
        System.out.println(Queue1.size());
        }
}
```

But the size of queue displayed is 0 as soon as I am outside the loop. I want the size of queue only increase and never go 0. Please help!!

All the variables are defined in the class so no worries son that part.

Comment: Yeah, but without showing how the queue is generated and handled, you're not going to get answers.

Comment: Posting a [mre] with your question will be your best bet at getting serious and decent answers quickly. Please read the link fully.

Comment: This current code is poorly formatted and won't compile either. Yes, a [mre] where you simplify the problem and the code will again be your best bet.

Comment: As an aside, I'd very strongly encourage you to start following normal Java naming conventions. Currently your methods and variables are named in a way that is inconsistent *and* doesn't follow the Java conventions.

Comment: You should add more details, all the classes that you use. And please, Use camel case naming convention for classes and objects! `Create_queue` class should be `CreateQueue`,  `Coflow_each` variable should be `coflowEach`...

Comment: There are many classes, I will end up adding lot of code. Do you think link to git hub will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [poll()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html#poll()) which by contract mutate the queue: returns and removes the element from it.

Use `next()` method from the iterator to preserve the elements:

```
Iterator<Create_queue> it = Queue1.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next().toString());  // <-- get element and do not remove it
}
System.out.println(Queue1.size()); // will not be 0.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes Thats the issue and now my program is not returning size 0.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like he code block below is iterating over your collection and removing all elements.

```
    java.util.Iterator<Create_queue> it = Queue1.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(Queue1.poll().toString());
    }
    System.out.println(Queue1.size());
```

I think the intent of the code above is to print the contents of the queue to the screen, then display the total number of elements it contains.

However, because you are using poll(), which retrieves AND removes the item (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) you are removing all of your elements.

To actually print the elements you will need to do something like what is written at this SO answer [Print out all elements of a stack/queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799687/print-out-all-elements-of-a-stack-queue)

Comment: Thank you so much yes thats the real issue